# porque funciona toda mi funcion pero no los mensajes de alerta?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy teniendo un error con mi formulario, no me esta mostrando los mensajes de alerta. Lo que es raro es que no me esta devolviendo ningun error en la consola.

```js
        function validarFormulario(){
    
            var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            
    
            if (nombre == ""){
                alert("Por favor escriba su nombre y apellido");
    
            }
    
            if (tel == ""){
                alert("Por favor escriba su telefono");
            }
    
            if( email == ""){
                alert("Por favor escriba su E-mail");
            }
    
        }
```

```html
 <tr>
            <td width="60%" align="left" valign="top">Nombre y apellido</td>
            <td width="40%" align="left" valign="top"><input name="nombre" type="text" onchange="validarFormulario();" onkeyup="validarFormulario();" id="nombre" size="40" maxlength="100">
              *</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Telefono</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="tel" onchange="validarFormulario();" onkeyup="validarFormulario();" type="tel" id="tel" size="40" maxlength="40">
              *</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Email
              <input name="micorreo" type="hidden" id="micorreo" value="delfibergalli@gmail.com" onchange="validarFormulario();" onkeyup="validarFormulario();" ></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="email" type="email"  id="email" size="40" maxlength="100">
              </td>
          </tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="button" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar"></td>
```

Hice unos console log de mis variables y me devuelve los valores pero no entiendo porque no estaria mostrando los mensajes de alerta. Algun error que no este viendo por el cual no muestra los mensajes? Ya revise todo varias veces y aún asi no logro encontrar donde me equivoque.

Comment: Tu codigo si muestra los mensajes

Comment: Es probable que solo te falte ejecutar la validación al tratar de enviar el formulario.

Comment: Fíjate que estas usando ```onchange``` en tus ```inputs```, hasta que no escribas algo en uno de ellos no te va a lanzar los **alerts** que esperas.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder solucionar tu problema utiliza la librería de [sweetalert](https://www.programmerall.com/article/75651104137/) ya que está se verá muchísimo mejor cuando se ejecute y se solucionara tu problema de ejecución de código.

```
// ENVIO DEL MENSAJE
       if (mail != '') {
       swal("Su mensaje fue enviado, pronto estaremos en contacto. Gracias.";)
       } else {
       sweetAlert({
       title: "Oops!",
       text: "Something went wrong on the page!",
       type: "error"
       });
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

La validación seria ideal hacerla al momento de apretar el botón Enviar. Con tu onchange en cada input estas validando al momento de que se presione alguna tecla.

Por lo que hice algunos cambios en tu código.

1. Quite los `onchange` y `onkeyup` de cada input.
2. Meti todo el `<tr>` dentro de las etiquetas `<form>` con el evento `onsubmit`, el cual llama al evento `validarFormulario()`
   Esto permite que al momento de apretar enviar, se llame a la funcion y se valide que cada input cumpla con la condición.
3. Cambie el tipo de botón a `submit` para que el formulario pueda ser procesado al presionar Enter.

Por tanto, quedaría de la siguiente forma

```js
 function validarFormulario(){
    
            var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            
    
            if (nombre == ""){
                alert("Por favor escriba su nombre y apellido");
    
            }
    
            if (tel == ""){
                alert("Por favor escriba su telefono");
            }
    
            if( email == ""){
                alert("Por favor escriba su E-mail");
            }
    
        }
```

```html
     <form onsubmit="validarFormulario()">
         <tr>
                <td width="60%" align="left" valign="top">Nombre y apellido</td>
                <td width="40%" align="left" valign="top"><input name="nombre" type="text"  id="nombre" size="40" maxlength="100">
                  *</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">Telefono</td>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="tel"  type="tel" id="tel" size="40" maxlength="40">
                  *</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">Email
                  <input name="micorreo" type="hidden" id="micorreo" value="delfibergalli@gmail.com"  ></td>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="email" type="email"  id="email" size="40" maxlength="100">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar"></td>
         </tr>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque la condición no se cumple. Cuando el campo no tiene valor `nombre` es `=` a `null` si es null ponle ""

```
var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value || "";
```